# Why thread does not stop after execution?

Tags: python, events, tkinter, python-multithreading

Hello I wrote simple program that resizes images in for loop. I want to show every image when resize is done. When resized image has shown I want my program to wait for tkinter button press. Everything works fine, but when I call destroy() method thread called resizer does not stop. Could anyone point me out why this happens? Please take a look at full example:

```
import argparse
import os
import threading
from PIL import Image
import tkinter as tk


def resize_images(args, evt, root):
    images_names = os.listdir(args.src_dir)
    for image_name in images_names:
        evt.clear()
        image_path = os.path.join(args.src_dir, image_name)
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        img.show()
        resized_img = img.resize((56, 56))
        resized_img.show()
        evt.wait()
    root.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--src_dir", default="Data")
    opt = parser.parse_args()
    event = threading.Event()
    root = tk.Tk()
    t1 = threading.Thread(name="resizer", target=resize_images, args=(opt, event, root))
    t1.start()
    root.title("Manage program execution")
    button = tk.Button(root, text='Next', width=25, command=event.set)
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    t1.join()
```

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Because it is not a daemon thread (`daemon` option not set to `True`), so the thread will not be terminated even the main window is destroyed.  Set `daemon=True` in `t1 = threading.Thread(...)` and remove the line `t1.join()`.

Comment: @acw1668 That was it! Thank you very much!